# How to append to a text in a file

Tags: c#, file

I have a file which has the following contents:

```
#Mon Jun 16 14:47:57 EDT 2014
DownloadDir=download
UserID=1111113
InputURL=https\://sdfsfd.com
DBID=1212
VerificationURL=https\://check.a.com
DownloadListFile=some.lst
UploadListFile=some1.lst
OutputURL=https\://sd.com
Password=bvfSDS3232sdCFFR
```

I would like to open the file and modify the contents, to add `|TEST ONLY` to the end of the `UserID`. The edited file will be this:

```
#Mon Jun 16 14:47:57 EDT 2014
DownloadDir=download
UserID=1111113|TEST ONLY
InputURL=https\://sdfsfd.com
DBID=1212
VerificationURL=https\://check.a.com
DownloadListFile=some.lst
UploadListFile=some1.lst
OutputURL=https\://sd.com
Password=bvfSDS3232sdCFFR
```

How can I achieve it?

I so far have the ability to read all the lines from a file. This is what I have:

```cs
if (File.Exists(strRootPropertyFile))
{
    string[] lines = null;
    try
    {
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(strRootPropertyFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    if (lines != null)
    {
        //find the line with the UserID
        //add `|TEST ONLY` at the end of the UserID
        //Overwrite the file...
    }
}
```

Comment: What part are you having problems writing?

Comment: loop and `if(line.StartsWith("UserID")` then `line += "|TEST ONLY"`

Comment: I am not sure how to find the line and append to it. I am guessing I have have to read and overwrite the existing file. Would it be easier to just clear the file content and write the contents again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop between lines and check if the line start with the `"UserID="` string and add the string you need. After it, create a new file and overwrite the current file using the [`File.WriteAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, and `string.Join` using the `Environment.NewLine` (break line) as separator.

```
if (File.Exists(strRootPropertyFile))
{
    string[] lines = null;
    try
    {
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(strRootPropertyFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    if (lines != null)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            if (lines[i].StartWith("UserID="))
                lines[i] += "|TEST ONLY";               

        File.WriteAllText(strRootPropertyFile, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best to do, I think, is to:

- Read the file line by line
- Write the lines, possibly modified, into another file.
- Remove the original one.
- Rename the new file!

Comment: I am guessing I can clear the content and add new contents... was trying to avoid it but thank you :)

Comment: How about something like this: `FileStream fStream = File.Open(strRootPropertyFile, FileMode.Append)`?

Comment: @SiKni8 FileMode.Append may not let you modify the existing content in-place. Even if it did, with having to move the cursor and everything it would be far simpler to just re-write the file.

Comment: Append will help you only if you want to write to the last line.